# Multi-Monitors: Locking machine moves windows to different monitors

Tags: macos, display, high-sierra

I am using a macbook with two external monitors.  Frequently, I lock the computer, my windows are on a different screen then when the computer was locked.

For example:

- Open PyCharm on monitor #1
- Open Chrome, iTerm2, etc on monitor #2
- Lock computer
- (Maybe wait for a few minutes?)
- Unlock computer
- Windows are now *randomly distributed*.  This may mean any of the following:

  - Windows are reversed - PyCharm is now on monitor #2 and everything else is on monitor #1
  - All windows are on monitor #1
  - All windows are on monitor #2

There seem to be multiple variants of this problem.  It seems to occur both when the lid of the laptop is open and when it is closed.  I haven't used the computer with a single external monitor, so not sure if the issue occurs then.  One related issue is that sometimes it will not recognize one or both of the monitors and I need to unplug/replug the monitor to allow the computer to recognize the monitor.

Info on my system:

[image]

And monitors:

[image]

(Maybe related) Mission Control:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and changing the cables / adapters fixed it.
My 2 monitors were plugged through an hdmi-hdmi cable going in an hdmi-usbc adapter. Changing one of these to an hdmi-usbc cable fixed the problem.